# Showing discard and save buttons when objects aren't equal

Tags: angularjs

In the controlller I have this code when the template loads:

```
$scope.pristine_timesheet = angular.copy($scope.timesheet);
```

In the template I want to do this:

```
<div ng-show="(timesheet != pristine_timesheet)">
  <div class="button-bar">
    <a class="button button-positive" ng-click="update(form)">Save changes</a>
    <a class="button button-stable" ng-click="discard(form)">Discard changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason this is always showing the buttons.  I know I could use $dirty but wondering why this isn't working.

Comment: Because when you copy the object to another variable they both have different references, it will always fail equality comparison. You can just use $dirty special property. Or you would need to do deep comparison on object properties.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by extending the class in the service like this:

```
  angular.extend(Timesheet.prototype, {
    compare: function(timesheet){
      return ((timesheet.id == this.id) && (timesheet.notes == this.notes) && (timesheet.task_link_id == this.task_link_id) && (timesheet.time_start == this.time_start) && (timesheet.time_end == this.time_end));
    }
```

In the template I can now simply do:

```
<div ng-show="!(timesheet.compare(pristine_timesheet))">
```

Thanks PSL for the explanation.  I also tried with lodash isEqual but that one didn't work for me: https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual

Comment: But your solution will not be scalable at all. IMO you should have a more abstract algorithm to check for deep equality.